Add a empty row between rows differentiated by key_cols
In order to distinguish rows in listing by key_cols variable by variable, it would be nice to have a empty row in between, there is an example:
library(rlistings)
adae <- ex_adae
lsting <- as_listing(
  df = adae,
  disp_cols = c("ARM", "AGE", "SEX", "RACE", "AEDECOD", "AESEV"),
  key_cols = c("USUBJID", "AETOXGR")
)
head(lsting, 15)

then we have:
Unique Subject Identifier   Analysis Toxicity Grade   Description of Planned Arm   Age   Sex             Race              Dictionary-Derived Term   Severity/Intensity
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-134                 2                      A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                                              A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                       3                      A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd B.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                                              A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.4.2             MODERATE     
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-141                 1                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd D.2.1.5.3               MILD       
                                                            C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.1               MILD       
                                                            C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.1               MILD       
                                       2                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                       3                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd B.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                       5                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-236                 5                      B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                              B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                              B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-265                 2                    C: Combination         25     M              WHITE                  dcd C.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                       3                    C: Combination         25     M              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.4.2             MODERATE     

It would truly be nice to have a row in between each person, be like:
Unique Subject Identifier   Analysis Toxicity Grade   Description of Planned Arm   Age   Sex             Race              Dictionary-Derived Term   Severity/Intensity
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-134                 2                      A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                                              A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                       3                      A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd B.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                                              A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.4.2             MODERATE     
  
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-141                 1                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd D.2.1.5.3               MILD       
                                                            C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.1               MILD       
                                                            C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.1               MILD       
                                       2                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                       3                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd B.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                       5                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
  
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-236                 5                      B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                              B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                              B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
  
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-265                 2                    C: Combination         25     M              WHITE                  dcd C.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                       3                    C: Combination         25     M              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.4.2             MODERATE     

Thank you for looking into this!

One hacky way would be to manipulate the data prior to listing by splitting the data by USUBJID, adding a blank row to each, and then combining them back together.
library(dplyr)

adae <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(ex_adae, ~USUBJID), \(x) {
  y <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, ncol(ex_adae)), nr=1)), names(ex_adae))
  y$USUBJID <- unique(x$USUBJID)
  rbind(x, y)
}))

This removes the variable labels, which can be fixed using the sjlabelled package.
library(sjlabelled)
adae <- copy_labels(adae, ex_adae)

lsting <- as_listing(
  df = adae,
  disp_cols = c("ARM", "AGE", "SEX", "RACE", "AEDECOD", "AESEV"),
  key_cols = c("USUBJID", "AETOXGR")
)

head(lsting, 15)


Unique Subject Identifier   Analysis Toxicity Grade   Description of Planned Arm   Age   Sex             Race              Dictionary-Derived Term   Severity/Intensity
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-134                 2                      A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                                              A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                       3                      A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd B.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                                              A: Drug X            47     M              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.4.2             MODERATE     
                                                                                                                                                                       
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-141                 1                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd D.2.1.5.3               MILD       
                                                            C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.1               MILD       
                                                            C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.1               MILD       
                                       2                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd A.1.1.1.2             MODERATE     
                                       3                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd B.2.1.2.1             MODERATE     
                                       5                    C: Combination         35     F              WHITE                  dcd D.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                                                                                                                                       
  AB12345-BRA-1-id-236                 5                      B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                              B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      
                                                              B: Placebo           32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        dcd B.1.1.1.1              SEVERE      


Here is one way adding NA rows displayed as empty strings:
library(dplyr)
adae_blank <- bind_rows(adae, data.frame(USUBJID = unique(adae$USUBJID))) %>%
  arrange(STUDYID)
  
lsting <- as_listing(
  df = adae_blank,
  disp_cols = c("ARM", "AGE", "SEX", "RACE", "AEDECOD", "AESEV"),
  key_cols = c("USUBJID", "AETOXGR"),
  default_formatting = list(all = fmt_config(na_str = ""))
)
head(lsting, 15)

      USUBJID          AETOXGR        ARM         AGE   SEX             RACE                 AEDECOD       AESEV  
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
AB12345-BRA-1-id-134      2        A: Drug X      47     M              WHITE             dcd A.1.1.1.2   MODERATE
                                   A: Drug X      47     M              WHITE             dcd A.1.1.1.2   MODERATE
                          3        A: Drug X      47     M              WHITE             dcd B.2.1.2.1   MODERATE
                                   A: Drug X      47     M              WHITE             dcd D.1.1.4.2   MODERATE
                                                                                                                  
AB12345-BRA-1-id-141      1      C: Combination   35     F              WHITE             dcd D.2.1.5.3     MILD  
                                 C: Combination   35     F              WHITE             dcd A.1.1.1.1     MILD  
                                 C: Combination   35     F              WHITE             dcd A.1.1.1.1     MILD  
                          2      C: Combination   35     F              WHITE             dcd A.1.1.1.2   MODERATE
                          3      C: Combination   35     F              WHITE             dcd B.2.1.2.1   MODERATE
                          5      C: Combination   35     F              WHITE             dcd D.1.1.1.1    SEVERE 
                                                                                                                  
AB12345-BRA-1-id-236      5        B: Placebo     32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN   dcd B.1.1.1.1    SEVERE 
                                   B: Placebo     32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN   dcd B.1.1.1.1    SEVERE 
                                   B: Placebo     32     M    BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN   dcd B.1.1.1.1    SEVERE


thank you! we had this kind of "Plan B" manipulating empty row in dataframe before rlistings, but all variable labels lost......
